# how to create mysql join query for get equal value in two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables..

```
id | name | email
```

and

```
 id | school | class
```

I need a SQL query to select equal id and get a school name, how can it be done?

Comment: please reword your question, it is hardly understandable.

Comment: Thats very good question. Use **inner join**. My opinion is "please read mysql documantation or basic mysql queiries". Best of luck to your sql journy.

Comment: What does both id represents?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Research, try something, add your code & point your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple. Use `Inner Join`:

```
select t1.id,t2.school
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2
on t1.id = t2.id;
```

Kindly go through the [Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
select * from tabl1e,table2
```

Comment: That's a cross join. It won't get the desired result.

Comment: You need to add extra column 'table1_id' in table2, then you use join and get perfect result, for more detail refer https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html